# Start new line automatically when otherwise content would overflow cell

Tags: google-sheets, text-formatting

I don't know when Google changed the version of Spreadsheets. Right now when the cell's text is longer than the cell width the display of this line is no longer what it used to be. I want the display of the text to be broken into lines when it is too long, as before.

I've made two examples [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SMwAeR-mWONtCqz2bQJ7vTlmiNvcYOy9cc_8j3z6xUY/edit#gid=0):

[image: WA66203 question example]

Cell 1: Since there is no content in the cells adjacent to the right, content is displayed over the cells beside it, which makes the cell look like a super long combined cell.

Cell 2: Since there is content in the cell beside it, much of the content is hidden automatically. People cannot see the content unless the cell is clicked.

How can I make such text automatically break into enough lines that all is visible?

Comment: @pnuts, no. Just wrap text. How can I do that?

Comment: @pnuts, Cool ,it works! Thx alot!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

With the gradual roll out of new Google Sheets from very [late 2013](http://googleblog.blogspot.co.uk/2013/12/new-google-sheets-faster-more-powerful.html) onwards the default text wrapping behaviour changed from [“on”](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/141104?hl=en) to “off” (which suits me). So what may have been taken for granted now requires a conscious choice, though only to select the range to which wrapping is to be applied and clicking a button:

[image: WA66203 example]

NB: As of May 2019 the icon now looks like this (the right most icon)

[image]

The button toggles.

Comment: Even selecting wrap, the content clips in my sheet. In other words, the cells do not become taller to accommodate the additional space needed. Perhaps another setting is preventing that to happen?

Comment: The comment by @Davide is relevant. The cell is not increasing in size. Maybe some bug? Or any other suggestions?